# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline + html5shiv.JS in vendors/assets/javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, asset-pipeline, html5shiv

After reading this [post](http://zoompf.com/2012/05/html5shiv-and-serving-content-from-code-repositories) (recommended reading) about not using HTML5Shiv direct from source like (almost) everybody does, I'm trying to include the html5shiv.js in my app using Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline.

I downloaded both minified and not-minified version of the javascript. The convention tells you to add third-party files into the vendors/assets folder. I have two questions now:

1) Which version (minified or not-minified) should I add to vendors/assets/javascrip folder?

2) Since it's a conditional reference `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`, how should I call the script?

I don't want to add it to the application.js manifest, because I want to keep it as a separate file and I want to use the condition. I'm kind of lost!

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the unminified version of the JS if you like, Rails will compress it in production mode through the pipeline.

To keep the shiv as a separate file you can give it it's own manifest by creating a `html5.js` (or whatever) in your `/vendor/assets/javascripts/` directory. In that file require the html5shiv (I assume the manifest and script are in the same dir).

```
//= require html5shiv
```

or

```
//= require html5shiv.min
```

And then include the manifest in your layout in the conditional block. In HAML something like:

```
== "<!--[if lt IE 9]>"
= javascript_include_tag 'html5'
== "<![endif]-->"
```

Remember to restart your app server before testing.

Comment: I tried what you said, and the HTML generated is this:     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/assets/html5shiv.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/html5.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

Both files have the same content and if I tried to access than using the  ?body=1 the show empty. If I remove the ?body=1 they are shown ok. But when I try to rake assets:precompile, the html5shiv.js is not compiled and when I run the server in production mode, I get an error. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess my assets weren't being served. Now everything seems to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Remember to add custom manifests to your  precompile list in `config/environments/production.rb` It has instructions, but an example: `config.assets.precompile += %w[html5.js]`

Comment: why not use the haml syntax for ie conditionals `/[if lte IE7]`...?

Answer (score 1):

Or you may use directly

```
/[if lt IE 9]
  %script{ src: "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js", type: "text/javascript" }
```